# Wordpress admin menu 

Tags: wordpress

I tried hundrad of times to load a custom page when top level menu items are clicked.

```
add_menu_page('Hotels', 'Hotels', 'administrator', 8, 'main_menu_foo');
```

Where should I put my "view-hotels.php" file?

I want to built a menu as

```
[Hotels]
  [Hotels]  //points to view-hotel.php
  [Add new...] // points to add-hotel.php
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add menu page needs a call back function to render the page. You can wrap your page in a function and add with an include or you could include the page using your callback function.  Also 'administrator' is not a capability.  Heres an example:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_admin_menus' )
function add_admin_menus() {
        add_menu_page( 'Hotels', 'Hotels', 'manage_options', call_back_function );
    }

call_back_function() { ?>
<div class="wrap">
<?php wp_nonce_field( 'hotels' );
hotels_page_function(); ?>
</wrap>

<?php }

include_once( '/view-hotels.php' );
```

Comment: No, this is not what I want. When you click Posts > Posts a php file edit.php is pointed.

Comment: [Try the docs:](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) Then look a look at [__file__](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_basename)